# composite functions help

Tags: discrete-mathematics, function-and-relation-composition

Let $A$ be a set and $f : A \to A$ be a function. Define

$$f^{(n)}=\overbrace{f\circ f \circ \cdots \circ f}^{\text{$n$ times}}$$

a. Find a sensible meaning for $f^{(0)}$

b. Prove or disprove: $(f\circ g)^{(2)} = f^{(2)}\circ g^{(2)}$

c. Prove or disprove: If $f$ is invertible, ${f^{-1}}^{(n)} = {(f^{(n)})}^{-1}$

Any suggestions? I don't really know where to start

Comment: Note that $f^{(a)}\circ f^{(b)}=f^{(a+b)}$.  What is the only sensible meaning then for $f^{(0)}$ noting that $f^{(n)}\circ f^{(0)}=f^{(n+0)}=f^{(n)}$.  As for part (b), you've heard I'm sure that $a+b=b+a$, that addition is commutative.  Have you been told whether or not function composition is commutative?  No?  Then that implies that there is some $f,g$ such that $f\circ g\neq g\circ f$.  Can you find such an example?

Comment: Yes sure...sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: by the definition you know that $f^{(n+1)} = f^{(n)}\circ f$.

For (a), we should have $f^{(0)} \circ f = f$. What function $A \to A$ doesn't do anything when composed with another function?

For (b), write our what $(f\circ g)^{(2)}$ and $f^{(2)}\circ g^{(2)}$ look like.  Remember that in general composition of functions is not commutative.

For (c), recall that a function $g:A \to A$ is an inverse of $f:A \to A$ if and only if $f\circ g= \mathrm{id}_A$.  Show that $(f^{-1})^{(n)} \circ f^{(n)} = \mathrm{id}_A$, so $(f^{-1})^{(n)} = (f^{(n)})^{-1}$.